# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (both strictly ordered): is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I must prove that $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (both strictly ordered, the second coordinate is the 'main' one) are not isomorphic.

I wrote a proof, but I don't know if it's rigourous enough or even correct, and I would be grateful for pointing out mistakes and guiding to how to do it better.

The proof is:

$\triangleleft$
In $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, for every ordered pair $\langle x, y\rangle $ (including the pairs of type $\langle x, n\rangle $) there exists a subset of ordered pairs that have the same first coordinate and lesser second coordinate: $\{\langle x, y-1\rangle , \langle x, y-2\rangle , \langle x, y-3\rangle , \dots\}$. The cardinality of this set is $\aleph_0$.

In $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$, for every ordered pair of type $\langle x, n\rangle $ there exists a subset of ordered pairs that have the same first coordinate and lesser second coordinate: $\{\langle x,n-1\rangle ,\langle x, n-2\rangle ,\dots\langle x, 1\rangle \}$. The cardinality of this set is $n-1$, where $n$ is a natural (and, therefore, finite) number.

Since isomorphism preserves the order, if sets $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, then their subsets $\dot A \subset A$ and $\dot B \subset B$ constructed by the same rule should also be isomorphic.
However, in our construction even cardinalities don't match: one is infinite, another one is not.
The Cartesian products in question are not isomorphic, therefore. 
$\triangleright$

I did search through the stackexchange and clicked the proposed links while writing this question, but, unfortunately, found nothing.

Thank you a lot!

---

Here's a new proof (note: in the proof above, $0$ was not considered a natural number; in the proof below, it is):

$\triangleleft$
The ordering: the major index is the second coordinate.

Assume the contrary:  $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $\langle 0, 0\rangle $ from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ is mapped to some $\langle a, b\rangle $  in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

With both $\langle 0, 0\rangle $ and $\langle a, b\rangle $ there is associated a subset of either $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ comprised of lesser elements:

$\{\dots, \langle -z, 0\rangle , \dots, \langle -2, 0\rangle , \langle -1, 0\rangle \}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ for $\langle 0, 0\rangle $,

$\{\dots, \langle x, b-1\rangle , \dots, \langle a-2, b\rangle , \langle a-1, b\rangle \}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ for $\langle a, b\rangle $.

Since isomorphism preserves the order,

$\langle a-1, b\rangle  \mapsto \langle -1, 0\rangle , $

$\langle a-2, b\rangle  \mapsto \langle -2, 0\rangle $ and so on.

Now, where would we map $\langle x, b-1\rangle $? We would have to map it to some element given by formula $\langle -z, 0\rangle $ (it's the only available option). However, between $\langle -z, 0\rangle $ and, say, $\langle -2, 0\rangle $ there is a finite amount of pairs, and between $\langle x, b-1\rangle $ and $\langle a-2, b\rangle $ there is an infinite one. But for isomorphism to exist, these amounts must be equal. Contradiction.
$\triangleright$

Comment: Isomorphic as what? $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is a group, the other not.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Isomorphic as sets. This exercise is from an 'Introduction to the Basics of the Set Theory' textbook for undergraduate freshmen students (it can be read after finishing High School, I believe). I am sorry, but I don't know yet what a group is, and the textbook also does not mention it.

Comment: @fragileradius.  The correct term for sets without structure is equinumerous.

Comment: @fragileradius.  For the structure you are considering, be clear by stating order isomorphic.

Comment: What does a dot over a letter mean? @fragileradius  Your proof is good if the first coordinate is the major index, ie dictionary order.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the second coordinate is the 'main' one"? What is 'main' about it? More particularly: Exactly how are you ordering $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb N$. It is obvious that orders can be put on these sets that are equivalent (after all, $\Bbb Z \sim \Bbb N$ as sets). So the answer to the problem depends very much on what ordering you are using, and calling the 2nd coordinate 'main' suggests you may not be referring to the most common choice.

Comment: You talk about the sets $\dot A$ and $\dot B$ as being "being constructed by the same rule". But the construction you described was only on $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb N$, and one of $A$ or $B$ would need to a subset of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ for this to be relevant.

Comment: @WilliamElliot
Thank you!
1)
The dots over the letters don't mean anything concrete. I thought denoting subset of X with a letter similar to X makes the proof more comfortable to read. $A_0 \space or \space A' $ could be used instead of $\dot A$ with the same purpose.  
2)
I ordered $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ this way:

${<}x, y{>}$ $\gt$ ${<}x', y'{>}$ $\iff$ $(y>y') \lor (y = y' \land x>x')$
The ordering of the subsets is the same.
So, the major index is the second coordinate.
Does this make the proof incorrect? Where?
Thank you.

Comment: You have the essential fact.  Proof is weak:  Let (0,0) in Z×N be mapped to (a,b) in Z×Z and apply your arguement to (0,0) and (a,b). @fragileradius

Comment: @WilliamElliot Thank you. I wrote a new proof (in the body of the question). Could you please tell me whether it's correct or not this time? Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: @fragileradius.   See my answer.

Comment: The `<` and `>` symbols should not be used for angle brackets in MathJax or LaTeX. The `\langle` and `\rangle` commands are designed for that purpose. This is especially important if you're likely to want to write something like $\langle x,y \rangle > \langle x', y' \rangle$.

Comment: So, is your 'new' proof correct  (assuming that the second coordinate is the 'main' one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All orders are in dictionary order.
(a,b) <= (x,y) when a < x or (a = x and b <= y)
N is set of positive integers.

NxZ not order isomorphic to ZxZ.  Proof.
Every subset of the lower set of (1,1) in NxZ has a maximum.
The subset {a-1}xZ of the lower set of (a,b) in ZxZ
does not have a maximum.

Is ZxN order isomorphic to ZxZ?

Answer (score 1):

In your proof you seem to have overlooked the fact that in the lexicographic order $<_L$ on either $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb N$ or on $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb N,$ there are infinitely many members between $(a-1,b)$ and $(a,b).$  The order being defined by $(x,y)<_L(x',y') \iff (x<x'\lor (x=x'\land y<y')). $

Suppose $f:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb N\to \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ were an order-isomorphism and $f(1,1)=(a,b).$  Then for $n\in \Bbb N$ we must have $f(1,n)=(a,b+n-1).$

For brevity of notation let $A=\{1\}\times \Bbb N$ and let $B=\{a\}\times \{b+n-1:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Then $f$ must  map the set $C=\{P\in \Bbb Z\times \Bbb  N: \forall Q\in A\;( Q<_LP)\}$ onto the set $D=\{P'\in \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z: \forall Q'\in B: (Q'<_LP')\}.$

But $C$ has a $<_L$-least member $(2,1)$ and $D$ has no $<_L$-least member because if $(p'_1,p'_2)=P'\in D$ then $p_1'\geq 2$ so $P'>_L(p'_1,p'_2-1)\in D.$

Comment: We could also consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on either set, where $P\sim Q$ iff the set of $R$ that are $<_L$-between $P$ and $Q$ is finite, And show that an order-isomorphism must map $\sim$-equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb N$ onto $\sim$-equivalence classes of $\Bbb Z\times  \Bbb Z.$ But equivalence classes, in the former, have least members, while equivalence classes in the latter do not.